# How to get Id Keys instead of objects from a @OneToMany relationship in JPA

Tags: jpa

How to receive only the list of id of a related table in JPA and not the list of whole Objects?
I don't want to find the id list from the object for performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

Umm... `SELECT item.id FROM RootEntity root JOIN root.relatedItems item WHERE root.id = :id`?

Or did you mean a `@OneToMany List<Long> ids` property? If so, then that's impossible in JPA, I'm afraid.

If your concern is about loading the entire state of a list of related objects when you only really need the ids, you could use an [entity graph](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-entity-graph-part-1-named-entity/). Just note that in order to be able to lazy-load simple properties, some JPA providers require entity enhancement to be enabled.